# Connecting second screen via Thunderbolt and HDMI

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, hdmi, mission-control

So my problem is the following:

At home I am connecting my MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra installed) to a second screen using the HDMI port. If I do that, and already have my mac running, on that second screen I have a new "Desktop" (i.e. in Mission Control) and all previously opened windows stay on the first desktop of my mac. This is the behaviour I like.

Now at work I am connecting with Thunderbolt. There, my "Desktop 1" gets transferred to the second screen, together with all my open windows, and I have a new empty Desktop on my mac.

So what I would like:

1. Get a consistent behaviour, no matter how I connect to a second screen.
2. Preferably, have the behaviour I get now when connecting with HDMI as default (i.e. the main desktop should always stay on my mac).

Anyone having experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a product that should be able to fix this issue for you:  [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/)

From their website:

> Stay can store a set of windows for every combination of displays that
>   you use with your computer. Stay can also be configured to
>   automatically restore windows as displays are connected and
>   disconnected.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually  hoping there would be a solution without additional software. To be clear: I don't need any functionality that goes beyond what is already working "out of the box" for HDMI connections, I just want the thunderbolt connection to be treated the same way...

Comment: That's two different connections actually.  One is HDMI and the other is DisplayPort, so it's two different monitor profiles.