# Secondary displays randomly swap content on reconnect

Tags: macos, display, displayport

I use a 2015 15" MacBook Pro with two external displays in the following approximate physical configuration:

```
+-----------+
|           +------------------------+
|           ||                       |
|           ||                       +-----------------+
|           ||                       ||                |
|           ||      2 (Primary)      ||                |
|     1     ||                       ||   3 (Built-in) |
|           ||                       ||                |
|           ||                       ||                |
|           +------------------------------------------+
|           |
|           |
|           |
+-----------+
```

Displays 1 and 2 are external, third-party displays. Display 3 is the laptop's built-in display. Display 2 is the primary display — the one with the menu bar in Display preferences' Arrangement tab. Displays 1 and 2 are attached to the laptop with two Mini DisplayPort cables attached to its two Thunderbolt ports, and are not daisy-chained — they're attached separately.

When I disconnect and reconnect the displays, there's about a 50% chance that the content that was previously on display 1 swaps with the content that was previously on display 3. When this happens, I typically just disconnect and reconnect both displays repeatedly until the content that was on display 1 is shown on display 1, and the content that was on display 3 is on display 3. The content on display 2 never seems to be moved.

How can I configure macOS to keep the arrangement of displays 1 and 3 correct?

---

Extra info:

- MBP model: MacBookPro11,4
- Display 1: Dell U2713HM
- Display 2: Dell U3011

Related question, though I don't believe it's a duplicate: [Primary display randomly changes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/42835/25686)

Comment: Possibly related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271690/119271

Comment: Related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441514/get-macbook-pro-m1-to-consistantly-order-2-identical-monitors

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Apple isn't interested in fixing this. FWIW you should tell Apple that you, too, care about this at http://apple.com/feedback