# How can one save iTerm2 hotkey-window settings (size/dimensions, computer monitor/display, and relative display position)?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, iterm

How can one save [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) hotkey-window settings (size/dimensions, computer monitor/display, and relative display position) so that the said hotkey window re-appears with the same (above) settings?

I'm looking for some sort of "saving current window settings" button/feature.

I'm finding the iTerm2 hotkey window also "auto changes" its dimensions undesirably when I move said window from one computer monitor/display to another, I'm guessing to match the Arrangement settings, or maybe something else.

I'm an iTerm2 newbie, and iTerm2 [Arrangements](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-arrangements.html) and [Profiles](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-dynamic-profiles.html) management do not yet behave in the way I want.

Comment: It's not an iTerm2 issue/feature.  You need something that will arrange windows for you (as you describe) in the way that you want.  Have a look at [Stay](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271690/119271)

Comment: @Allan - Stay.app looks great, extremely useful for several other scenarios I'm looking to solve--bravo. However, after some empirical testing with both Stay.app and iTerm2, I've been able to get what I want, independent of Stay (and I'm not sure Stay is yet doing anything for me...  yet). If/when I figure out what I did to achieve the desired behavior I'll post here.

Comment: Cool.  Be sure to ping me...I'll up vote!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I changed the iTerm2 preferences `Hotkey Window -> Window -> Style = No Title Bar` (see annotated screenshot below) it started doing what I want.

I believe the original setting was `Full-Width [something...]`. When I change the `Style` setting back to a `Full-Width` setting, it gets wonky again, namely it starts stretching the Hotkey Window to a full width of the screen. Makes sense.

What makes less sense to me is why `Full-Width` was set for this Hotkey-Window profile which I had not used previously. This suggests it might (?) be a default setting. If so, I'm not sure why the iTerm2 developers/managers want it this way, it seems like it would cause confusion for other newbies like me in the same scenario.

[image]

Comment: You genius! Spend last 3 hours trying to figure it out